# Multiple submit button on a single view

Tags: html

[image: multiple submit button on same view]

In the above image there are multiple updates button in front of various countries.when I am entering some value in any textbox and click on update button then always the first textbox value is saved in database.In above image it always save the value of the textbox which in front of "Australia".

Comment: This is not the image which I have posted.What is this??

Comment: According to the edit history it is. Feel free to edit the post and insert the correct image.